# Writing a simple SQL Server 2005 dynamic sql

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am writing a fairly simple SQL query in SQL 2005, but am running into an issue and can't figure out what is wrong.

For documentation purposes, the query has to be a dynamic sql

A snippet of my query is:

```
@RecCreatorID int
....
....
IF (@RRecCreatorID IS NOT NULL)
    Begin
        Set @strSQL = @strSQL + ' AND RecCreatorID = @RecCreatorID'
    End
```

However, when I run PRINT @strSQL, what I get is

**And RecCreatorID = @RecCreatorID**

How can I get the actual value of @RecCreatorID to be displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@RecCreatorID int
....
....
IF (@RRecCreatorID IS NOT NULL)
    Begin
        Set @strSQL = @strSQL + ' AND RecCreatorID =' +  cast(@RecCreatorID as varchar(50))
    End
```

another solution is to use `sp_executesql` to execute query

Comment: Why would I cast that as varchar if its an int in the proc ?

Comment: because @RecCreatorID is integer and @strSQL is varchar

Comment: Correct, but might lead to SQL injections. (Of course when @RecCreatorId is a string.)

Comment: Incredible. Thanks for the answer !!

Comment: i think sp_exeuctesql is better to use over here but condition is constrain over here

Comment: as opposed to Execute(@strSQL) ?

Answer (score 2):

Use sp_executesql. That stored procedure will accept parameters which you can then use inside your dynamic SQL (parameter substitution). For example:

```
Set @strSQL = @strSQL + ' AND RecCreatorID = @RecCreatorID_PARAM'


exec sp_executesql @SQL,
N'@RecCreatorID_PARAM int',
@RecCreatorID_PARAM = @RecCreatorID
```

Although this doesn't do much for displaying purposes, it's still a better way of handling dynamic SQL than concatenation, imho.